# How to get data from SQL server dimensions in to mongoDB

Tags: sql-server, mongodb

im trying to get my dimensions from SQL server into MongoDB, i can do it like this but then i have to write code for EVERY dimension which is kind of time consuming. Some pieces of the code:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("Nelly");
DBCollection facil = db.getCollection("Facilities");   

while (r.next()) {
BasicDBObject facObj = new BasicDBObject();

String faccKey = (r.getString("dim_Facilities_dKey"));
if (faccKey != null && !faccKey.trim().isEmpty()
&& faccKey.length() != 0)
facObj.append("dKey", faccKey);

facil.insert(facObj);
```

But i want to be able to do it faster with some kind of loop and list but i cant figure out how to solve it, i have tried everything!

```
while(r.next()){

for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {

HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashmap =  new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();       
arr.add(r.getString(i));


BasicDBObject facObj = new BasicDBObject();
String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
int varde=1;
String data =r.getString(varde);
varde++;
arr.add(data);

hashmap.put(name, arr);

facObj.append(name, hashmap.values().toString());
facil.insert(facObj);
```

Can someone give me advice on how to move on?

Thanks in advance

I solved it:

```
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = s.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (r.next()) {
BasicDBObject facObj = new BasicDBObject();
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++) {

String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

String faccKey = (r.getString(i));
if (faccKey != null && !faccKey.trim().isEmpty() && faccKey.length()!= 0)
facObj.append(name, faccKey); 

}
facil.insert(facObj);}
```

Comment: You shouldn't transfer a database schema designed for a relational database to a document-oriented database. The philosophies how they structure data are fundamentally different.

Comment: What exactly is the variable `r` in your code snippets? Some iterator, I presssume, but what exactly is it iterating?

Comment: ResultSet r = s.executeQuery();

Comment: Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
StringBuilder facilities = new StringBuilder();
facilities.append("SELECT * FROM dbo.dim_Facilities");
PreparedStatement s = connect.prepareStatement(facilities.toString());

Comment: r is a Resultset that iterates through all the values in the facilities dimension( i think, i hope)

Comment: you can edit your question. Please add that code to it for better readabilit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i solved it finally, i didnt even need the hashmap ;)

Comment: @kurtan86: If you found your own answer to the problem, it's fine to post as an answer below (rather than editing the question).

Answer (score 0):

this kind of task is usually done by a ETL tool, which is designed to do it, and can give you better performance and manageability.

Regards,
Moacy